# Is there a way to prefetch images via Haneke?

Tags: ios, objective-c, haneke

In SDWebImage it is possible to prefetch (early loading) images upfront like this:

```
[[SDWebImagePrefetcher sharedImagePrefetcher] prefetchURLs:<NArray with image URLs>];
```

Is there a way to achieve the same with [Haneke](https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke), please?

It seems there is a [Preload policy](https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke#preload-policy), but unsure how to utilise it, e.g. `HNKPreloadPolicyAll`

Comment: You might also check out [DFImageManager](https://github.com/kean/DFImageManager) if SDWebImage doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I needed this functionality today, and I found that if you loop through your array of URL's and call hnk_setImageFromURL with a temporary UIImageView, the images are cached.

```
- (void) cacheImagesInURLs:(NSArray <NSString*>*)array;
{
    for (NSString *path in array) {
        UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kMaxWidth, kMaxHeight)];
        tempImageView.hnk_cacheFormat = [self setImageCacheFormat];

        [tempImageView hnk_setImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path] placeholder:nil];
    }
}
```